# Custom hook to call Axios POST request and sending from data but response keeps saying product_id is empty

Tags: react-native, post, axios, multipartform-data, react-custom-hooks

I generally call apis using custom hooks so I'm trying to get a response  from axios POST call and the data needs to be passed as form-data plus it also needs params but for some reason, it keeps showing an error saying product_id is empty because this API works in postman

Custom hook

```js
const useProductDetails = ({ form }: ListProps) => {
  console.log("form:", form);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const fetchData = (data?: any) => {
    console.log("data:", data);
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: BaseUrl.baseurl + "product_detail",
      data: form ? form : data,
      params: { endpoint: "product_detail" },
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
      .then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
          setResponse(res.data);
        }
        console.log("datainside", data);
        console.log("responsedetail", res.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error123", error.response);
        setError(error.response.data.msg);
        console.log("errorcode", error.response.status);
      });
  };

  const callFunc = (data: any) => {
    fetchData(data);
  };

  return { response, error, callFunc };
};
```

Calling Custom hook

```js
const { response, error, callFunc } = useProductDetails({
    form: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    callFunc({
      product_id: "3",
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response !== null) {
      setproduct(response.data?.product_detail);
      console.log("responsedet", response);
    }
  }, [response]);`
```

Comment: plz include the whole error-message

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli {
    "error": true,
    "message": "product_id Is Mandatory"
} this is what it is returning